# Is it wise to install Ubuntu repositories in Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I have installed Debian 6.0.4 and I wanted to install software from repositories. But there are missing packages. So, as I used to be a Ubuntu user, I though I could use Ubuntu's repositories. After i've installed the list from http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/, i tried to install some software. But I get some alerts about untrusted sources.

Is it a wise decision to install Ubuntu related software to Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While theoretically it might work, it can cause problems when Debian and Ubuntu have different versions of packages; also, it can cause breakage when doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` if critical packages (like kernel, `glibc` etc...) are replaced.

Comment: thanks. i've also noticed that installing almost any ubuntu software from ubuntu repositories requires aditional ubuntu libraries.